# Upgraded to Spyder 5 IDE for Python; Missing spyder-kernels

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I recently upgraded [Spyder](https://www.spyder-ide.org/) to version 5.
When i open it I get the error message:

> The Python environment or installation......doesn't have the spyder‑kernels module or the right version of it installed (>= 2.3.0 and < 2.4.0).

The instructions to fix this suggest installing the missing kernals using

`conda install spyder-kernels=2.3` or `pip install spyder-kernels==2.3.*`

I tried installing it using conda (it is what we use for package management) however I got the following error:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - spyder-kernels=2.3.2

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org
```

I did as prescribed and can see at this [link](https://anaconda.org/search?q=spyder-kernels) that  conda-forge / spyder-kernels 2.3.2 exists.

I am a bit at a loss what to do from here. Can anyone help

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I did as prescribed and can see at this link that conda-forge / spyder-kernels 2.3.2 exists.

That is correct, but if you look at your output from the install:

```
Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
```

You have not configured `conda-forge` as a channel, try

```
conda install -c conda-forge spyder-kernels=2.3.2
```